# mysql company update date value is blank

Tags: mysql

I have a table company_update and have the following field:

ID                                      auto_increment
company_status               varchar(20)
company_update_date     date

For company_update_date field, if the value is blank, should I use **NULL** or '**0000-00-00**'? Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

**NULL** means "The data does not exist, or is unknown." **Date('0000-00-00')** essentially means, "This happened before time began." It's up to you, but I'd probably go with **NULL**.

Comment: yes i agree with @Darwin. Using NULL is prefered as it will be easy to filter data on date using is null otherwise,,,you have to compare it using 0000-00-00 .Also i suppose memory wise also NULL is prefered over 0000-00-00 date.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is is `better` because we can easily compare null value to other value

> But if `column` has been defined with `NOT NULL` or with a default
>   `'0000-00-00'`.  You need to change the column definition to `allow NULLs` and have no default.

Answer (score 0):

The Null is better to know as start point. Example : You create company but it still not active (Now you set Null) you decided will be active after one month will you insert the date. So, you can check the Active, Pending, till not active. As other colleague say depending on requirement.